# Error Transforming Document to String

Tags: java, xml, dom, transform, transformer-model

Let's see this link :

[HTML DOM Tree to String - Transformer NullPointerException](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11340779/2458559)

I got the same problem with him..but he can't solve it. I don't want to change from JBrowser to DJ Project. I'm curious with this problem. Any idea what's wrong with this problem?

Thanks!

**Edit:**

HTML file : http://www.uploadmb.com/dw.php?id=1372739472

This is method to transform document to string

```
public String getStringFromDocument(org.w3c.dom.Document doc) {
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    try {
         doc = browser.getDocument();
         DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(doc);
         StreamResult result = new StreamResult(sw);
         TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
         Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
         transformer.transform(domSource, result);

    } catch (TransformerConfigurationException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (TransformerException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (TransformerFactoryConfigurationError e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return sw.getBuffer().toString();
}
```

This is method to get specific element :

```
String html=getStringFromDocument(browser.getDocument());
//org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc;                    
this.doc=Jsoup.parse(html);
org.jsoup.select.Elements tableElements=doc.select("table");
org.jsoup.select.Elements rowElements = tableElements.select("tr");    
int k = rowElements.size();
for (org.jsoup.nodes.Element td : rowElements) {
    System.out.println(td.text());
    k = k - 1;
}
```

**Error** :

```
ERROR:  'Namespace for prefix 'collapse;table-layout' has not been declared.'
javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Namespace for       prefix 'collapse;table-layout' has not been declared.
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:736)
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:340)
at browser.component.JBrowser.getStringFromDocument(JBrowser.java:428)
at browser.component.JBrowser$9.actionPerformed(JBrowser.java:133)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:686)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:702)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:700)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:699)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Namespace for prefix 'collapse;table-layout' has not been declared.
at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serializer.SerializerBase.getNamespaceURI(SerializerBase.java:914)
at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serializer.SerializerBase.addAttribute(SerializerBase.java:431)
at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serializer.ToUnknownStream.addAttribute(ToUnknownStream.java:316)
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.parse(DOM2TO.java:201)
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.parse(DOM2TO.java:230)
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.parse(DOM2TO.java:230)
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.parse(DOM2TO.java:230)
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.parse(DOM2TO.java:136)
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.parse(DOM2TO.java:98)
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transformIdentity(TransformerImpl.java:683)
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:727)
```

### ... 39 more

Comment: I don't know enough of the details to know if it is impossible to work around, but given code and data that reproduces the error I'ld take a shot at a work around.

Comment: @eghm I've edited my post above.i hope you can clear the problem to us who has the same.

Comment: Seeing your error that reminds me of another thing you can try, run the page through JTidy before transforming it.

Comment: Still waiting on the jxbrowser license, but as a draft, I'ld suggest saving the page contents to a file (before transforming).  Create an input stream using that file, and run it through JTidy's Tidy.parse to get your Dom, then do the transformation.

Comment: @eghm not jxbrowser but jbrowser..jxbrowser still trial.

Comment: The concept should be the same, being able to get an input stream out of the browser would be ideal, but run it through Tidy.parse to get your Document, or skip the transformation and get the data you want a less correct but probably easier way such as I mention in the Answer

Answer (score 1):

You're using XML tools to process HTML, so you need to start by converting the HTML to XML. You can do that using for example JTidy or TagSoup.

Comment: if I use JTidy or another library, I think it can't work cause input to parse with JTidy is in string. But, I have org.w3c.dom.Document object of the current page displayed in the JBrowser component.

Answer (score 0):

Run the page through JTidy ( http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/ ) first.  Or if your solution doesn't have to be flexible, you could parse out the data you want using substrings or regular expressions.

Comment: sorry,I think your solution above is not good idea cause some people say regular expressions is bad. I have tried to get specific element from that document object with java DOM, but sometimes it return null pointer. It gets me more curious.

Comment: I agree not as good, but when I've had the same sorts of parsing behavior blocking me I've worked around it that way.